# c++ Carriage Return Line Feed long string followed by a shorter string

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, carriage-return

I have an application which I want to print status messages with. However, sometimes it occurs that a shorter status message follows a longer status message, which leads to the following situation:

Long message:

```
this is the long status message which is longer than the short one
```

Shorter message:

```
This is the short status messagewhich is longer than the short one
//this one should end here      ^
```

The code I'm using is:

```
cout << StatusMessage << '\r';
```

How can I overcome this problem and firstly erase the whole line before printing the new line? Preferably with a cross platform solution, but for now I'm working on Windows

***Note***: I already tried to overwrite the line with `\b` or `spaces`, however this may result in a multiple line cleaning which removes the functionality of my `\r` approach.

Comment: Please clarify, with example code and its ouput, what your problem was when you tried to use spaces

Comment: C++ doesn't have any concept of the console.  If you portability I would look for a console library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `'\b'` (backspace) repeatedly in the length of the former output for your case. It seems to be pretty [standardized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape):

```
cout << StatusMessage << '\r';
cout << std::string(StatusMessage.size(),'\b');
```

Comment: If I do this right behind each other it should print me an empty line right?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren It would step back to the beginning of the current line (I'm not even sure if the `'\r'` is really what you want there).

Comment: I replaced your second line with `cout << '\r' << string(StatusMessage.size(), ' ');` which works like a charm. Thanks